# master-detail style report with jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, report, master-detail

So, I have a report to make, and I need some help to clear up some doubts.

The report has to show information about 2 tables related in a one-to-many
fashion, like, a "post has many comments" kind of thing. So, in the detail
section data about "the post" and "the comments" related to it should be
printed, if any. My question is: is it possible to create such a report
with jasper?

Initially I thought of using a subreport to fill in the comments in the detail
section for each post, but couldn't figure out how could I use the ID of the
post to get the comments and fill the report, if it's possible at all that is,
and the tests made so far to try to use such ID haven't succeeded yet. Any
help or pointer to the answer (if it already exists at SO) will be appreciated.

Comment: It's possible. How is your datasource? Is it possible to show more details about it? Basically you join the two tables, group your data by post (at query level) and later (at "Jasper Report level") you can create group for each post.

You may also create a subreport for each post using the ID as parameters for the subreport query, but I think it's unecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do that. You might try with Jasper Groups, but it will require a query extracting data from a joint of the two tables. And as you're already trying with Sub-Reports, you should take a look at this post. It's quite straightforward: [Master-Detail JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/subreports)